# Apache Web server using flask, deploying my web app

Tags: python, apache, flask, web-deployment

I have a small flask application, and I am trying to host in on my website. It works whenever I run it on my computer, and connect via localhost:5000/ but when I upload to my server, and run the python code, i get multiple errors. When it runs, it only runs on localhost, and can be connected to via the servers console, but when I try to specify that it is to be hosted on all public facing ip's, it says operation not permitted.

here is the terminal output

```
`/home/public]$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in 
run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 
717, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

`

my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
port=33

@app.route("/")
def index():
    x = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    return render_template("index.html", stylevar=x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

if I connect via the domain name, and navigate to /templates, my index.html file will show, but it wont be running the python code.

Would really appreciate any direction on how to get it to be connected to from the browser. I understand that flask is not meant for production environments, but this is just a small personal project. If there are any other environments other than flask this could be accomplished in, I am willing to try something else.

Comment: Do you have some process already using the port 33 on one of your NIC?

Comment: @Adonis not that im aware of....how do I check that?

Answer (score 1):

The script does not have the rights for running with a port below of 1024. If you really need to use port 33 you have to run the script as root.